# How to add more than one feature into the same cell using the grid method, Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

There might be question like this, but I can't find it.
I want to have more than one entry or label etc. in the same cell without them overlapping. I hope you know what I mean.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Lynch For example, I would add an entry so it is row=0 column=0. Now if I then added a label to row=0 column=0, it would just go on top of the entry. Now I don't want to put it in row=0 column=1 because then it is spaced to far apart due to larger features being in that column. I want it so in this example, the label would be right next to the entry without affecting the gridding done before. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put as many items as you want in a frame, and then put the frame in the grid cell.

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# some random widgets, for illustrative purposes
l0 = tk.Label(root, text="Cell 0,0", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Cell 0,1", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
l2 = tk.Label(root, text="Cell 1,0", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
l3 = tk.Label(root, text="Cell 1,1", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
l4 = tk.Label(root, text="Cell 1,2", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")

# create a frame for one of the cells, and put
# a label and entry widget in it
f1 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
l5 = tk.Label(f1, text="Cell 0,2")
e1 = tk.Entry(f1)

# put the label and entry in the frame:
l5.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
e1.pack(side="top", fill="x")

# put the widgets in the root
l0.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
l1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
f1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
l2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
l3.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
l4.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean and how to go about this.

Comment: Thanks you, I would give you a thumbs up but I can't.